# Is it possible to run Gerrit's commit-msg script standalone, not as hook?

Tags: gerrit

1. I have no Gerrit hook installed
2. I have simple commit
3. I would like to check the Change-id of the commit

Is it possible to get the change id by running some command, for example

```
./commit-msg xyz
```

?

I don't want to use Eclipse. I don't want to configure hook.

Comment: What do you mean with "check the Change-ID"? The Change-ID just needs to be some unique identifier. The hook IIRC only generates that, if there's no `Change-Id` line.

Comment: I want to generate change-id. <joke>then print and put in wallet</joke>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `commit-msg` script assumes to be run as Git hook (see [example file](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/tools/hooks/commit-msg)). Therefore, it makes couple of assumptions.

Executing it stand-alone (you just could have tried that, right?) fails with

> sed: : No such file or directory

Thus, **no**, you cannot run this standalone.

You might be able to fix it to work when called manually, but I'm unsure about your motivation. You sound like you don't want to install anything, but [`git-review`](https://github.com/openstack-infra/git-review) is a nice helper.

Comment: Thanks. My motivation: I wanted to push trivial change to rarely used repository without changing my environment

Comment: Adding a hook to that repo is not really changing your (complete..) environment. It's one file in that repo. Just do it :p

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to manually install the commit-msg hook in every repository you clone. You can configure Git to do this job for you automatically. When you execute the clone command Git copies a repository template located at:

```
Linux = /usr/share/git-core/templates
Windows = C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/share/git-core/templates
```

If you add the commit-msg hook to the template it will be installed automatically for every cloned repository.

However, the best thing to do is the following:

1. Create a personal template (e.g. $HOME/.git-templates)
2. Install the commit-msg in $HOME/.git-templates/hooks
3. Configure Git to use your personal template:

   git config --global init.templatedir $HOME/.git-templates

Comment: Thanks for answer, it is simple and step-by-step clear instruction. Anyway, I appreciate gerrit, I use gerrit, `commit-msg` hook is excellent, but I don't like anyone force me to modify my laptop environment. In current case I want keep my `git` unmodified because I use git for many projects, not only gerrit hosted. So impossible. Pity.

Comment: In this case, when needed, you can just add the Change-Id line manually. It's really easy... just write "Change-Id: Ixxx" (xxx = any 40 hexadecimal sequence). You can have a default value (let's say: 3bfe5cf1bc941a37f4dd0900f3c053c6dfdb6589) and every time you change 2 or 3 characters. It's enough.